# The approximation function of $\frac{x}{y}$

Tags: approximation, approximation-theory, linear-approximation

Is there a approximation function of $$\frac{x}{y},$$ and the approximation function is in the form of $f(x) + f(y)$ or $f(x) - f(y)$. That's to say the approximation function can split $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Not sure what you want.  Since $\frac xx=1$ (at least for $x\neq 0$) we need $f(x)+f(x)=1$ or $f(x)-f(x)=1$, neither of which seems likely to lead anywhere.

Comment: What are the possible values for $x$ and $y$ ? There will probably not be an approximation of the desired type good for all pairs $(x,y)$

Comment: There is no such approximation in any neighborhood of a point at which $y=0$ and $x\ne 0,$ since the quotient approaches $\infty$ at such points. At other points where $x\ne 0,$ there is a tangent plane, and that gives you a linear approximation. $\qquad$

Comment: @lulu Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Peter Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks a lot, and what's the linear approximation when $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @UniMilky : Let's try the point $(x,y)=(1,1).$ then $\dfrac\partial{\partial x} \,\dfrac x y = \dfrac 1 y$ and $\dfrac\partial{\partial y} \, \dfrac x y = \dfrac{-x}{y^2}.$ The values of those two derivatives at $(x,y)=(1,1)$ are respectively $1$ and $-1$. Therefore $\Delta\dfrac x y \approx 1\cdot\Delta x + (-1)\cdot\Delta y.$ Since the value of $x/y$ at $(x,y)=(1,1)$ is $1$, that yields $$ \begin{align} \frac x y & \approx 1 + 1\cdot\Delta x + (-1)\cdot\Delta y \\  \\ & = 1 + 1(x-1) + (-1)(y-1). \end{align} $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Got it,Thanks!

Comment: $\log \tfrac xy=\log x - \log y$

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is unspecific about what constitutes an "approximation", the answer appears to be "no".

As lulu notes in the comments, an approximation $\frac{x}{y} \approx f(x) + f(y)$ leads (for $x = y$) to
$$
1 = \frac{x}{x} \approx f(x) + f(x) = 2f(x)\quad\text{for all $x$.}
$$

Similarly, an approximation $\frac{x}{y} \approx f(x) - f(y)$ leads (for $x = y$) to
$$
1 = \frac{x}{x} \approx f(x) - f(x) = 0.
$$

---

From the other direction (i.e., starting with customary notions of approximation and seeing where they lead):

If $y_{0} \neq 0$, then for $|y - y_{0}| < |y_{0}|$ the geometric series gives the first-order approximation
\begin{align*}
  \frac{x}{y} &= \frac{x}{y_{0} + (y - y_{0})}
  = \frac{x}{y_{0}} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + (\frac{y - y_{0}}{y_{0}})} \\
  &= \frac{x}{y_{0}} \cdot \left[1 - \frac{y - y_{0}}{y_{0}} + \bigg(\frac{y - y_{0}}{y_{0}}\biggr)^{2} - \cdots\right] \\
  &\approx \frac{x}{y_{0}} - \frac{x(y - y_{0})}{y_{0}^{2}},
\end{align*}
which is not of the form you seek.

Comment: The idea is clearly,Thanks a lot.